# Jmeter Proxy setup (Might be old topic)

Tags: proxy, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter tool, 
I have read couple of entries on the same topic. I tried my best extent still not possible to configure the proxy settings in jmeter......

```
started: jmeter -H xxxxxxxx -P 8080 -u u829755 -a German@12345 -N localhost
Browser: HTTP Proxy: localhost and port 9091
Jmeter(HTTP Test Script Recorder): port: 9091
```

Note: No other entries for (URL Patters to Include or exclude)

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

1. You are passing `-N localhost` to JMeter startup script which means ["No proxy for `localhost`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

   > `-N`
   >
   > [nonproxy hosts] (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
2. You are setting the browser to use `localhost` as a proxy. Therefore all requests which are being made on localhost are being made without proxying and JMeter cannot properly capture them.

So the hints are:

- Try removing this `-N localhost` from your JMeter startup command line
- If you're recording HTTPS traffic you will need to import `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` into your browser, see "HTTPS recording and certificates" chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) user manual entry for details
- [Increase JMeter log verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)
- If you're using a browser which proxy settings are integrated with operating system proxy settings (Internet Explorer/Edge/Safari/Chrome) - it might be the case your whole operating system cannot access the Internet or application under test, try switching to a browser which has separate proxy configuration like [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/)

  ```
  <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />
  ```

  JMeter restart will be required to pick the change up. Once done check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input....  I removed the "-N localhost" and started Jmeter... still same issue exists... ,                                                                       
started: jmeter -H xxxxxxxx -P 8080 -u u829755 -a German@12345 - I understood the port mentioned in the command line is for proxy server port.. please correct me... In the browser, HTTP Proxy "localhost" and port "9091" is for jmeter listening port? please correct me...